# OmegaFlightStore.com, is it reliable to book flights from this site?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources

I want to book a flight from Zurich to CDG. I came across that this site provides a cheapest flight details. Therefore I need to know how reliable this site is for flight booking? Is there anyone who has book flights using this flights?

Comment: It appears to be ATOL and ABTA registered, which is probably a good sign it's legitimate

Comment: I would suggest that if random-OTA-with-poor-reviews provides cheapest flights then you are not looking hard enough.

Comment: They are ok if you just want to travel without ever needing to contact them over the phone or email. They are NOT a scam company its just that they can't/won't manage post booking enquiries/requests smoothly. If you are even a tiny bit sceptical about your plan to change the dates then don't book with them. I have used them twice in the past and both the time it was last minute booking so I just booked online and travelled without needing to contact them.

Answer (score 9):

I have used them for a flight from Manchester UK to Las Vegas in November 2016 and everything was fine. Also used them for an upcoming flight from Manchester UK to Chicago in September.

My flight to Las Vegas had connections(one in Paris and one in the USA) and they all went fine, I even missed the connection in the USA(due to immigration) and delta who the flights were with sorted me a later flight without a problem.

The flights I just booked to Chicago were all confirmed quick, these flights are with British Airways and I can manage my booking through the BA website now so all good on their system too.

Comment: How do we know you're not a scammer from that site. All these are just anecdotes, no real evidence.

Comment: @theonlygusti: If he's a scammer, he's really playing the long game, because he made his account 7 months ago and has answered four other questions having nothing to do with online travel booking.

Comment: Im not a scammer... just trying to be helpful. I used them through SkyScanner if that makes any difference and I doubt SkyScanner let scamming companies use their platform.

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah, sure, it's improbable but not impossible. Compromised account? Just happened to also be a profiteer from that scam site? Who knows. As I said, I feel like this answer needs evidence

Comment: What evidence would you like? I can give you all my flight numbers if you want @theonlygusti

Comment: @theonlygusti no disrespect- you're being silly. As stated in the other answer they're atol and abta registered

Answer (score 6):

Well, based on Google search results I wouldn't personally use them, but it's your personal choice. As mentioned earlier, they are ATOL and ABTA registered, and there are people that say it's reliable, just slow. [Trustpilot](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/omegaflightstore.com), [Twitter](https://twitter.com/hashtag/omegaflightstore) have a fair amount of warnings about them making a lot of mistakes and overall the reviews seem quite poor.

Based on the reviews online, as long as you get your confirmation and tickets in time, don't get your flight cancelled and don't need to refund, you should be fine. Always use third-party bookings sites with your own discretion.

Answer (score 3):

I have used them once. Everything went fine, so they are not a complete scam at least. I don't know how they are if you need to make changes or a flight is cancelled.